# Trying to build a very simple C++ project

Tags: c++

This is a very simple question that I cannot figure out.

I have three files `Car.h`, `Car.cpp`, and `main.cpp`

`Car.h`

```
class Car{
    private:
    
    public:
    void printNumWheels();
    Car() {};
    ~Car() {};
};
```

`Car.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Car.h"

using namespace std;

void printNumWheels(){
    cout << "four wheels";
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "Car.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Car car;
    car.printNumWheels();
}
```

When I run `g++ car.cpp` I get the following error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "Car::printNumWheels()", referenced from:
      _main in main-8cdc4f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any ideas why that might be? Is there a different way I need to build the project? Or do I need to specify Car::printNumWheels() somewhere?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You have two .cpp files but you build the app with only one file.

Comment: When I run `g++ main.cpp Car.cpp` it looks like I get the same error

Comment: Please show me where `Car::printNumWheels()` is defined.

Comment: Oh ok changing printNumWheels() to Car::printNumWheels() in Car.cpp fixed the issue. Thank you for your help

Comment: It's irritating when two errors produce the same diagnostic, but it can happen.